# Springboot testing with keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to run simple unit test, Keycloak is configured in proper way( I tested it and my mvc app is connecting and users are authenticated_ but now I tried to test my controllers and even though 
I used spring slices  keycloak adapter is invoked and giving me errors. Adapter configuration is mostly brought from keycloak documentation

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {



    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        reset(userService);
    }

    @Test
    void logout() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/logout"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

but I've got errors when I try to run it, stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:205)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:37)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.doFilter(KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:182)
    at org.czekalski.userkeycloak.controller.UserControllerTest.logout(UserControllerTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:532)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:171)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:167)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:114)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

adding to test `@TestPropertySource("classpath:secTest.properties")` where inside secTest.properties
`keycloak.enabled = false` didn't help

code under test:

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    private final UserService userService;

    public UserController( UserService userService) {

        this.userService = userService;
    }



    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String logout(){
        return "users/logout";
    }


    @GetMapping("/logged")
    public String loggedIn(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("token",   userService.getloggedInUser());
        return "users/logged";
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the test scope Spring configuration?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just wrote a set of libs [to ease unit-testing of secured Spring apps](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons).

It includes a `@WithMockKeycloackAuth` annotation, along with Keycloak dedicated `MockMvc` request post-processor and `WebTestClient` configurer / mutator

Sample usage:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(GreetingController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = GreetingApp.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { KeycloakSecurityComponents.class, KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class })
public class GreetingControllerTests extends ServletUnitTestingSupport {
    @MockBean
    MessageService messageService;

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloackAuth
    public void whenUserIsNotGrantedWithAuthorizedPersonelThenSecretRouteIsNotAccessible() throws Exception {
        mockMvc().get("/secured-route").andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloackAuth("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")
    public void whenUserIsGrantedWithAuthorizedPersonelThenSecretRouteIsAccessible() throws Exception {
        mockMvc().get("/secured-route").andExpect(content().string(is("secret route")));
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockKeycloakAuth(
            authorities = { "USER", "AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL" },
            id = @IdTokenClaims(sub = "42"),
            oidc = @OidcStandardClaims(
                    email = "ch4mp@c4-soft.com",
                    emailVerified = true,
                    nickName = "Tonton-Pirate",
                    preferredUsername = "ch4mpy"),
            privateClaims = @ClaimSet(stringClaims = @StringClaim(name = "foo", value = "bar")))
    public void whenAuthenticatedWithKeycloakAuthenticationTokenThenCanGreet() throws Exception {
        mockMvc().get("/greet")
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(startsWith("Hello ch4mpy! You are granted with ")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("AUTHORIZED_PERSONNEL")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("USER")));
```

Depending of how much of the tooling I propose you wish to you might get `spring-security-oauth2-test-addons` or `spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons` from maven-central:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-test-addons</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.4</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

First is enough if you're only interested in `@WithMockKeycloakAuth` annotation. Second adds fluent API (MockMvc request post-processor) and other stuff like MockMvc wrapper with default values for content-type & accept headers

Comment: Well, good job! Back then I solved it in different way. Solution posted in separate thread.  I have to also test your solution :)

Comment: In version `2.3.4` there is no annotation `WithMockKeycloakAuth ` but `WithMockAuthentication` instead. Another point, I didn't find the method `mockMvc()` either. Any suggestions?

Comment: @WithMockKeycloakAuth is there in 2.3.4: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2-test-addons/src/main/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/security/oauth2/test/annotations/keycloak/WithMockKeycloakAuth.java

Comment: There was a typo in maven dependency snippet. Sorry. My lib supports KeycloakAuthenticationToken with MockMvc only (not WebTestClient) so should pull spring-security-oauth2-test-webmvc-addons instead of spring-security-oauth2-test-webflux-addons as test dependency

Comment: Last suggestion, plz do read READMEs, specially the part about cloning the repo locally to experiment test samples. You'll save lot of time configuring your own tests.

Answer (score 2):

Solution for the Keycloak + Spring Security setup during testing is tricky but IMHO the following is only proper solution to test properly set environment. First thighs first we do not want to use security config conditionally as we want to test it also (RolesAllowed, Post and Pre annotations for example). We do not want to create special configuration for test also for the same reason. The way out is the following configuration:

```java
@Configuration #mandatory
@EnableWebSecurity #mandatory
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true) #conditional
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class) #mandatory
@Slf4j #conditional
class WebSecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(@NotNull HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public @NotNull KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

}
```

The really important is the presence of `@EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakSpringBootProperties.class)`. Without it you will get NPE during tests. To you application.yml in the test resources or application-test.yml (the same goes analogically for the properties configuration) add the following:

```yaml
keycloak:
  enabled: false #Keycloak is not needed in full functionality
  realm: mock #There is no configuration mock for Keycloak in case of testing. Realm must be set but it is not used
  resource: mock #There is no configuration mock for Keycloak in case of testing. Resource must be set but it is not used
  auth-server-url: http://mock #There is no configuration mock for Keycloak in case of testing. URL must be set but it is not used
  bearer-only: true # Because Keycloak do redirect in case of unauthenticated user which leads to 302 status, we switch to strict Bearer mode
  credentials:
    secret: mock
```

With this setting and `@WithMockUser` annotation your `@WebMvcTest` will be running in the same security config as production with not errors.

Comment: After trying lot of things it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

I also found a way to do it, but it's quite ugly way. You can just turn off keycloak for testing purposes. Can be better?

in properties file(my is app-dev.properties) set:

```
keycloak.enabled = false
```

In application security config class I set

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "keycloak.enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
public class KeycloakConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

I also created separate class with security config but only for testing purposes with these annotations

```
@Profile("app-dev.properties")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class TestSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{}
```

In integration test of controller

```
@ActiveProfiles("app-dev.properties")
@WebMvcTest(value = FunController.class)
@Import(TestSecConfig.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:app-dev.properties")
class FunControllerIT{}
```

source:

> workaround https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6514

Answer (score 1):

You could also annotate your Testclass with `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)` to disable filters from the application context.

Answer (score 0):

Another angle would be to just test your Controller the same way you would test a Service (without @WebMvcTest annotation).  After all we don't really need to test Spring's functionality of routing GETs and POSTs and returning HTTP responses.  Spring tested that themselves. We are just concerned with testing the unit of work that **we** wrote... the guts of the controller functions themselves.

```html
@ExtendWith(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Mock
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    void logoutShouldShowUsersLogout() throws Exception {
        var result = logout();
        assertEquals(result, "users/logout");
    }
}
```

Just a thought.